# Como enviar formulário e como deixar sem refresh

Tags: php, html, formulário, email, envio-de-email

Estou tentando enviar meu formulário para o meu email, mas só retorna a mensagem "No arguments Provided!". Não sei o que eu estou errando.

E gostaria também de saber como faço para enviar o formulário e aparecer a mensagem de enviado no próprio index.html sem dar refresh na página ou ir para outra página. E depois de enviado, limpar o formulário.
Alguém poderia me dar uma ajudinha por favor?

formulário - index.html

```
<form action="mail/contact_me.php" method="POST" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Nome:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" required
            data-validation-required-message="Por favor, coloque seu nome.">
          <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Telefone:</label>
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefone" required
            data-validation-required-message="Coloque seu telefone.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required
            data-validation-required-message="Preencha seu email.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label>Mensagem:</label>
          <textarea rows="5" cols="100" class="form-control" id="mensagem" required
            data-validation-required-message="Digite sua mensagem" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="success"></div>
      <!-- For success/fail messages -->
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" id="sendMessageButton">Enviar Mensagem</button>
    </form>
```

---

página email - contact_me.php

```
    <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['nome'])      ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['telefone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['mensagem'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['nome']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['telefone']));
$message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['mensagem']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@seudominio.com'; // Adicione seu endereço de e-mail entre o '' substituindo yourname@seudominio.com - Este é o lugar para onde o formulário enviará uma mensagem.
$email_subject = "Contato via site | Web Net Informática:  $name";
$email_body = "Você recebeu uma nova mensagem do formulário de contato do seu site.\n\n"."Aqui são os detalhes:\n\nNome: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nTelefone: $phone\n\nMensagem:\n$message";
$headers = "De: yourname@seudominio.com\n"; // Este é o endereço de e-mail da mensagem gerada. Recomendamos usar algo como noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Você precisa colocar o nome do parâmetro no atributo `name` do `input`. Está dando `No arguments Provided!` porque não existem inputs com os nomes que você espera no servidor. Por exemplo, no input de nome você deve colocar

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" required name="nome"
            data-validation-required-message="Por favor, coloque seu nome.">
```

Para fazer requisição sem dar *refresh* na página você tem que usar `ajax`. Dê uma olhada sobre `ajax` nesses links [W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)
[MSN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que nenhum dos campos do formulário possui um `name`. Na verdade você colocou id's em vez de `name`. É o valor do atributo `name` que é recebido no backend. Se os id's não possuem função, troque-os por `name`, por exemplo:

em vez de `id="nome"`, coloque `name="nome"`, isso em todos os campos.

Se os id's tiverem alguma função, basta acrescentar o `name` também, por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" required...
```

Agora, para enviar o formulário sem dar refresh na página, você pode usar AJAX. Se você usa jQuery, consulte a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), ou com JavaScript puro pode consultar [esta documentação](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) como base. Pode também pesquisar aqui no campo de pesquisa por "AJAX" que tem muito material e exemplos disponíveis.